# Remove all TestCases associated to a TestSet

Tags: extjs, rally

With Rally SDK 2.0 APIs, I want to associate new TestCases to a given TestSet. To do this I :

1. initialize a store:

   ```
   me.selectedTestCasesStore = myTestSet.getCollection('TestCases',{...});
   ```
2. Remove all items (I don't want to keep them):

   ```
   me.selectedTestCasesStore.removeAll();
   ```
3. Add the new TestCases

   ```
   me.selectedTestCasesStore.add({'_ref':aTestCaseRecord.data._ref});
   ```
4. Then synchronize

   ```
   me.selectedTestCasesStore.sync({...});
   ```

Step 1 is OK : `console.log(me.selectedTestCasesStore)` shows me the collection in `data.items[]`.

Step 2 seems OK as a `console.log(me.selectedTestCasesStore)` shows me nothing in `data.items[]` (previous records are gone).

Step 3 is OK because added test cases which were not present at step 1 are now in the collection

Step 4 : Called function is "success"

**BUT**... only new TestCases are added, the old ones are not removed, as if step 2 has no effect. What's wrong in my code ? I extract the part of the concerned code :

```
// me.selectedTestCasesStore : my store, with old TestCase associated to a TestSet.
// It is initialized with something like :
//    me.selectedTestCasesStore = myTestSet.getCollection('TestCases',{...});
//
// selectedTestCasesArray : an array of records with the new TestCases to assign to the test set.


_removeAllFromSelectedTestCaseStore:function()
{
    var me = this ;
    console.log('In _removeAllFromSelectedTestCaseStore');

    me.selectedTestCasesStore.addListener({
        clear : me._addSelectedTestCasesToSelectedTestCaseStore,
        scope : me,
    });

    // Remove all associated TestCases from selectedTestCases store
    me.selectedTestCasesStore.removeAll();
},


_addSelectedTestCasesToSelectedTestCaseStore:function()
{
    var me = this ;
    console.log('In _addSelectedTestCasesToSelectedTestCaseStore');

    console.log('      After remove, store is now :',me.selectedTestCasesStore);

    // Add each check TestCase to selectedTestCases store
    for (var i=0; i < me.selectedTestCasesArray.length; i++)
    {
        // Add it to the collection
        me.selectedTestCasesStore.add({'_ref':me.selectedTestCasesArray[j].data._ref});
    }

    console.log('      After add, store is now :',me.selectedTestCasesStore);

    // Synchronyze
    me.selectedTestCasesStore.sync(
    {
        success: function(batch, options) {
            //success!
            console.log('      Success', me.selectedTestSetStore);
        },
        failure: function(batch, options){
            console.log('      Faillure :(', me.selectedTestSetStore);
        },
    });
},
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me instead of removeAll():

```
 var testcases = testCaseStore.getRange();
 _.each(testcases, function(testcase) { 
     testCaseStore.remove(testcase);
 });
```

Here is the full js file that empties the test case collection on a test set before adding a new test case

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        console.log("launch");
       Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
            type: 'TestSet',
            success: this._onModelRetrieved,
            scope: this
        });
    },
    _onModelRetrieved: function(model) {
        console.log("_onModelRetrieved");
        this.model = model;
        this._readRecord(model);
    },

     _readRecord: function(model) {
        var id = 16805375409;
        console.log("_readRecord");
        this.model.load(id, {
            fetch: ['Name', 'FormattedID', 'TestCases'],
            callback: this._onRecordRead,
            scope: this
        });
    },

    _onRecordRead: function(record, operation) {
        console.log('name:', record.get('Name'));
        console.log('test cases:', record.get('TestCases'));
        if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
             var testCaseStore = record.getCollection('TestCases', {
                autoLoad: true,
                listeners: { load: function() {
                    var testcases = testCaseStore.getRange();
                    _.each(testcases, function(testcase) { 
                        testCaseStore.remove(testcase);
                    });
                    testCaseStore.sync({
                            callback: function() {
                             console.log('test cases after removeAll():', record.get('TestCases'));
                        }
                        });
                    testCaseStore.add({'_ref':'/testcase/14469886070'});
                    testCaseStore.sync({
                        callback: function() {
                             console.log('test cases after add():', record.get('TestCases'));
                        }
                    });
                }}
            });
        }

    }, 
});
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug with using removeAll but the above workaround should get you by...

Comment: Thanks, the workaround works. But, maybe another bugs in the API : First, if I don't reload the testCaseStore after the first sync, the add and the second sync have no effects : my testset is empty, nothing is added. If I reload the testCaseStore after the 1st sync, it's OK, old testcases are deleted and new ones are added. And then, if the testCaseStore is empty before remove it, none of the sync callback are called. Now, with workaround and a reload after the sync, it works !